# Keyboard and Mouse not working in XDM

Tags: freebsd, keyboard, login-manager, xdm

I have a fresh install of FreeBSD 13 on a computer. I have i3-gaps as WM and rxvt-unicode as my ONLY installed terminal. I have followed the docs and enabled XDM login in ttys as per the [docs](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/x11/#x-xdm). I have also tried following the [FreeBSD forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/added-xdm-now-stuck-in-a-loop.49093/) where someone had an identical issue and solved it by `echo "kern.vty=vt" >> /boot/loader.conf`

I have tried enabling dbus, hald and xdm in rc.conf but that does not change anything. I do not have network access inside single mode, but could gain it by uninstall XDM if really necessary.

No errors in xserver or any other logs anywhere inside xdm folder or ~.

I have a minimal .Xsession with only `i3` in it, since I do not need to start anything else. Changing this to anything else, such as `exec i3`, changes nothing about the error.

I cannot go to another console using `ALT + CONTROL + F1`/F2, etc since the keyboard is completely disabled. I did not have this issue with sddm and slim in my previous two FreeBSD installs on this computer.

Comment: The X server's log tells you, and potential answerers, what keyboard and mouse devices the X server thinks that it is using.  Answerers won't get very far if you do not show them logs.

Comment: @JdeBP there is no difference in the X server logs from when I uninstall XDM and install sddm. sddm works perfectly fine, keyboard and everything. The keyboard and mouse is loaded exactly the same when I use XDM and sddm.

Comment: Answerers do not know that.  You (still) aren't showing the X server logs that tell them what keyboard and mouse devices, if any, are used by the server.

Comment: @JdeBP How can I show the logs from a computer that has no internet connection and cannot mount any USB drives? I am telling you it basically says "<Microsoft TM keyboard ... loaded>" or something like that. That's it. There is no awesome mention of mouse/keyboard anywhere. Do you get a brilliant insight from that or are you going to continue harassing me about basic text output? It isn't sentient you know? It won't say the exact errors its "feeling" as to solve all my issues magically.